# Eclipse Embedded C: Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project "project_name"

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded

When I try and build my Embedded C project in Eclipse, I get the error below after the build gets to around 37%. I think it may have something to do with generating the hex and binary files from project_name.elf, but I'm not sure given the error message.

```
`Errors occurred during the build.
 Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'project_name'.
 Internal error building project project_name configuration Debug
 Empty command
 Internal error building project project_name configuration Debug
 Empty command`
```

I've tried different versions of MinGW and the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain, and I haven't had any luck.

Comment: 37% of what?  What is the basis for that metric? Generating a hex from elf would be a post -build step, so if it is doing that, it would near 100%.  Randomly trying stuff is not going to get you far.  You have posted only the final error message.  The useful diagnostic information often appears before that - post the entire log.  If you have an elf file generating a hex file is a matter of applying a tool such as objcopy.  Do you have that as a post build step?

Comment: _"Errors occurred during the build"_ refers _exactly_ to preceding error messages.  Read the log from the top, the bottom is usually just "something broke, take a look".

Comment: It would also help to know, HOW you created/setup the project in Eclipse. "empty command" looks like you haven't setup the commands in the project at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem with MCUXpresso, which is NXP's CDT-enabled Eclipse-based IDE when using the "Internal builder" **"Builder type"** instead of using the default (make) "External builder". This setting is found in the project's settings at the "C/C++ Build" page in the "Builder Settings" tab.
In my case the error message only appears after all compilation units have been compiled and the final binary has been linked successfully (for unknown reasons).